# can I use web sockets to reduce server load?

Tags: ajax, websocket, webserver

I have a web application that makes 100 AJAX requests per second to the server from 1 client. Now the issue is my server is overloaded and I am currently load balancing the server with high cost. So can I use web sockets instead of AJAX requests will that reduce the server load?

Comment: there's a good chance it will, yes, if you do it correctly. Each individual HTTP request has a large overhead associated with negotiating the connection etc, even if the amount of data sent ends up being tiny.

Comment: I have the code in python on the server side. So is there and suggestion what web server that I use in the back-end?

Comment: I would guess you can still use python with websockets. Why don't you research and see if it has a module for handling that already?

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will look into it.